# Unable to load file class in Code igniter

Tags: file, codeigniter, model-view-controller

im new to php. Recently im doing a page where you can create a miniblog and uplolad a file. But when i click the submit button, theres error that said "Unable to load File class" can anyone help me to see where i do wrong?  thankyou in advance.

this is my form (view) code where user submit their files

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "<?= base_url().'admin/blog/addblog_post' ?>" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" placeholder="Add a file">
  </div>
  <br>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add mini blog</button>
  </form>
```

This one is from the controller where the addblog function is located

```
function addblog_post()
    {

        print_r($_POST);
        print_r($_FILES);

        if($_FILES)
        {
            //Image can be uploaded
             $config['upload_path']       = './assets/uploads/blogs';
             $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
               

                $this->load->library('file', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        die("Error");

                        // $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                        echo "<pre>";
                        print_r($data);

                        // $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
        }
        else
        {
            //Image cannot passed

        }

    }
```

Comment: what's the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no library with the name "file" in CI

if you want to upload a file you can make use of File upload library

change
`$this->load->library('file', $config);`
to
`$this->load->library('upload', $config);`

for more info go through [Libraries list](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/index.html) and [File Upload Library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: thankyou sir, i was using the wrong library name the whole time